# Program that finds the number 1 in more than one Text file and uses a Thread for each file / Segmentation fault(Core dumped) error

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, readfile

I'm facing a problem in my homework that I can't solve, can you help me? I am compiling via terminal in Opensuse Leap 15.4. As I mentioned in the title, there will be 10-20 text files in the same directory as our main program, and this text file will consist of 1 and 0. As a program parameter, text file names will be given from the terminal and I will open this text file and find the number 1 in it. More than one text file can be given as a parameter to the program in the terminal. I will run a Thread that will read the contents of each text file.

I wrote a code, it compiles without errors. However, I get the "Segmentation error(core dumb)" error, when I parameterize the program from the terminal. Even though the files are in the same directory, I can't read them at all. Here I will share my source code, which parts should I change, what are your recommendations?

Example :

```
./main 1-10.txt 3-10.txt
Total Number of Ones in All Files: 11

./main 8-10.txt 5-10.txt 4-10.txt
Total Number of Ones in All Files: 14

./main 
Total Number of Ones in All Files: 0

./main 1-10M.txt 2-10M.txt 4-10M.txt
Total Number of Ones in All Files: 15001073

--> I will run 3 Threads for 3 text files here to read

./main 8-10.txt xyzqw.txt
Total Number of Ones in All Files: 3

--> It will not read the content of the xyzq.txt file that is not in the directory and will not give an error.

./main *-10M.txt
Total Number of Ones in All Files: 24647735

-->> A program that can work in harmony with wildcards characters
```

Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int global = 0;

void* func(void *argp) {
  char buffer[500];
  char *c = argp;
  sprintf(buffer, "%s", c);
  FILE *fp = fopen(buffer, "r");
  char ch;

  if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("No text file , Number of 1 : 0");
  }
  do {
    ch = fgetc(fp);
    if ((int) ch == 1)
      global++;
  } while (ch != EOF);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int ar = argc - 1;
  pthread_t thread[ar];

  if (argc >= 2) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= ar; i++) {
      pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, func, (void*) argv[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= ar; i++) {
      pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
    }
  } else {
    printf("Filename not entered, Number of 1 -> 0 ");
  }

  printf("Number of Ones All files %d", global);

}
```

Comment: Some minor improvements: `char ch;`  --> `int ch;` to avoid an infinite loop.  `sprintf(buffer, "%s", c);` --> `snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%s", c);` to avoid buffer overflow.

Comment: I made the corrections you mentioned, but I am getting a Segmentation Fault warning, thank you for your attention.  @chux-ReinstateMonica

Comment: Please _append_ code with these minor corrections and the good changes suggested by @David Ranieri.  Also code should exit when `fp == NULL`, not continue on.

Comment: I added the changes, but when I export a file like ./main 1-10.txt, instead of reading the content, I get a "Segmentation fault(core dumped)" error as a result. I'm also wondering if I need to add the directory where the Main program is located? Text files are already in the same directory as the program.@chux-ReinstateMonica

Comment: 1) Does code immediately exit after `printf("No text file , Number of 1 : 0");` when `fp == NULL`?  2) Good that you have added the changes, Yet others do not see them exactly.  You can post you own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
pthread_create(&thread[i - 1], NULL, func, (void*) argv[i]);
```

instead of

```
pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, func, (void*) argv[i]);
```

otherwise you access outside of the bounds of the array in the last iteration.

To keep it simpler you can modify the `main` arguments:

```
  if (argc > 1)
  {
    argc -= 1;
    argv += 1;

    pthread_t thread[argc];
 
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
      pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, func, argv[i]); // you don't need the cast
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
      pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your corrections and your time.But I can't fully solve the problem. When I enter the ./main 1-10.txt file as a parameter, I get a "Segmentation Fault(core dumped)" error while waiting for it to read the numbers 1 in it.